# Avarage velocity of a planet in a parabolic orbit

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, orbital-motion, velocity, planets

How the average velocity of a planet (over the entire time; $t = 0$ to $\infty$) orbiting a star in a parabolic orbit can be calculated?

If it's instantaneous velocity is $v$ (at distance '$r$' from the planet), then from energy conservation principle,

$\dfrac{1}{2}m_{planet}v^2 - \dfrac{GM_{star}m_{planet}}{r} = -\dfrac{GM_{star}m_{planet}}{2a}$ $\Longrightarrow v = \sqrt{GM_{star}\left(\dfrac{2}{r}-\dfrac{1}{a}\right)}$ (so-called [Vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation))

If we think at $t=0$, $r \rightarrow -\infty$ and $v = 0$, then $v_{avg}$ should be,

$v_{avg} = \dfrac{\int_0^\infty v dt}{\int_0^\infty dt}$, which blows up! How this can be done? Is it at all possible to find $v_{avg}$ over the entire time $(0 \leq t \lt \infty)$? (At $t \rightarrow \infty$, clearly $r \rightarrow \infty$ and again $v = 0$. So the expression of '$v$' should converge and hence the integration should also converge. Is it not?)

Answer (score 0):

A planet orbiting a star is a periodic phenomenon, which means you can integrate from zero to $T$ (the period of the planet around the star).
$$v_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}vdt$$
there also another method for computing $v_{avg}$ simply by dividing the distance over time $v_{avg}=\frac{p}{T}$ where $p$ is the perimeter of the ellipse
$$p=4a \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-e^2 \sin^2 \theta}~d\theta$$
where $e$ is the ellipse eccentricity
$$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$$
($a$ and $b$ are the semi-major and semi-minor axis).
the perimeter formula above can't be expressed in elementary functions, but it can be approximated by many other formulas, one of the best ones is
$$p=\pi(a+b)\left(1+\frac{3\gamma}{10+\sqrt{4-3\gamma}} \right)$$
where
$$\gamma=\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)^2}$$
this formula is excellent (its error is $O(\gamma^{5})$) and it only gets better the more eccentric the ellipse is (the closer $e$ is to 1).
if you want a formula with an arbitrary precision you can use
$$p=\pi(a+b) \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \binom{0.5}{n}^2 \gamma^n$$
if you are a python user you can use the `hyp2f1` function from `scipy` 
I hope this answer helps you. :)

Comment: OP used the word, "orbit," but OP also said, "parabolic." The motion of an object making a parabolic pass around a star is _not_ periodic. The object will make just one pass, and it will never return. OP also said, "At →∞
, clearly →∞..." so, it seems is if they really meant to say "parabolic," and "orbit" was maybe just because they didn't know they could say "trajectory" instead.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, oh i see, i missed the point by a mile Lol, you are right, a better word would be trajectory, and should've been more focused. but in the case of a parabolic trajectory shouldn't the average velocity be zero?

Answer (score 0):

The expression for the average that you have is not well-defined. The integral in the denominator is divergent, and I would not be surprised if the one in the numerator is as well.

The average speed should be 0. Consider that the planet spends an "infinite amount of time infinitely far away" from the star, so however fast it moves when it is close to the star is completely canceled by the infinite amount of time where it barely moves at all, and the average comes out to zero.

To show this with your formula, I would suggest re-defining your initial condition so that the planet is at the closest point of contact at $t=0$.
Then perform the integral only for a finite time-range, $\int_{-T}^T$ and examine what happens when you make $T$ larger. The result should then approach zero the larger $T$ becomes.